# Accessing specific value from SASS nested list

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have the following sass variable:

```
$color-config:(     "white":    #FFF, 
                    "black":    #303133
);
```

and i would like to access the 'black' value (#303133) without make a loop. Something like that:

```
body
    color: $color-config("black")
```

*(i know, its completely wrong, its just to explain what i want)*

Comment: So you know, that's a list, not a nested list. It's one-level deep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use SASS's maps to store values inside variables:

```
$color-config:(
   white: #FFF, 
   black: #303133
);
```

Then use [`map-get()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map) to access it (see [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/)):

```
content: map-get($color-config, white); # will return #FFF
```

*In other words, don't use double quotes `"` around your variable name.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$color-config:(
    'white': #FFF, //quotes are important
    'black':    #303133
);

@function colors($value) {
  @return map-get($color-config, $value)
}

.white-font {
color: colors('white')
}
```